# Getting Values out of List<IEnumerable>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

I want to extract the two independent results set from a stored procedure execution into variables. I am using the following code to execute the stored procedure.

```cs
         var results = new RulesEngine2()
         .MultipleResults("[re].[spShift]", Params)
         .With<ResidentShift>()
         .With<ResidentHours>()
         .Execute();
```

What I want is to take results[0] and store it in a variable defined as ResidentShift. I also want to take results[1] and store it in a variable defined as ResidentHours.

Help is definitely appreciated!

Comment: The answer is that we would do it the same way as we would get values of out `List<Anything>`. It's no different from `List<int>`, `List<string>`, etc. `var firstItemInList = results[0]; var secondItemInList = results[1];` It looks like you're using [this code](https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures). The problem is that no one reading your question knows that. (I had to Google pieces of your code.) So no one can look at this and understand that `result` is a `List<IEnumerable>`.

Comment: I realize that sometimes it's hard to know which details are or are not relevant. In this case the question is how to get values from a `List<T>`. What `T` is (`IEnumerable`, anything else) is irrelevant. That you're calling a stored procedure is also irrelevant. What happens is that someone reading this will try to figure out what `RulesEngine2`, `MultipleResults`, `With`, and `Execute` are, when actually none of that has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ResidentShift temp, ResidentHours temp2) = results.Select(t => (t[0], t[1]));
```

Try this.

Its hard to know how to extract information if the type of results is unknown. But something similar to this will also work.

```
(ResidentShift temp, ResidentHours temp2) = (results[0], results[1]);
```